# Ubuntu 18.04 EPSON ET-2750 scanner not found

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

The printer function worked without configuration, but the scanner is neither detected by simple-scan nor by imagescan. I installed the drivers from Epson according to this [guide](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/03/26/ubuntu-epson-scanner-quick-start-guide-2/2/) and modified the scanners IP Address in /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf, which is mentioned [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/imagescanv3_e.html#sec6-1), but it doesn't help. Appreciate each suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this doesn't insult your intelligence, and I assume that you've tried it, but make sure that the comments (semicolons) are removed from the imagescan.conf file.

Additionally, install nmap (sudo apt-get install nmap) and run:

nmap -p 1865

The port (1865) should be open.

Comment: It doesn't just flatter my intelligence, but yes, it was due to the semicolons. I come out as ubuntu newbie. Anyways, thanks for your response!